# sorting select results using values from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, posts and comments. Each post has at least one comment. My tables look like following

The `post` table has post id `pid` and a `title`. The `comments` table has post id `pid`, comment id `cid` and timestamp `ts`

```
table post {
   int pid 
   varchar title
}

table comments {
   int pid
   int cid 
   int ts
   varchar comment
}
```

I like to list all the posts sorted by showing the post with the latest comment on the top.

I tried `group by` but it did not work as expected

```
select p.pid, c.ts from posts p, comments c where c.pid=p.pid group by p.pid order by c.ts desc;
```

I also tried

```
select p.pid, c.ts from posts p join (select pid, max(ts) from comments) c on c.pid=p.pid order by c.ts desc;
```

but it did not return any results.

Can someone help

Comment: Could you post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE comments;

Comment: Please also post TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE posts;

Comment: Please post the 2 SHOW CREATE TABLE xx; requested a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempt with `group by` was close.

The thing is that you need to order by the *maximum* timestamp of the group, which implies using an aggregate function in the `group by` clause.

In many databases, your query would have failed because the ordering column is not part of the `group by` clause... but not in MySQL.

```
select p.pid, max(c.ts) last_ts
from posts p
inner join comments c on c.pid=p.pid 
group by p.pid 
order by max(c.ts) desc;
```

Note: always use explicit, standard joins rather than old-school, implicit joins.

Comment: thanks, any comment on the performance penalties of max(c.ts) when number of posts are over 100k

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.pid, max(c.ts) as latest_comment
from posts p
left join comments c on c.pid=p.pid 
group by p.pid 
order by latest_comment desc;
```

You can also use `c.cid` intead of `c.ts` to speed up performance in cid is primary key for comments table.